# XMLMultiPageEditorPart document

Tags: java, overriding, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to override XMLMultiPageEditorPart's method doSave(). The point is to save data in temp file, validate it with XSD, and in case of success fire the method super.doSave(). But  getDocument() method is invisible. How can I perform manual document saving to predefined location?

```
public class TPXMLEditor extends XMLMultiPageEditorPart {
public static final String ID = "com.companyname.somemanager.gui.editors.TPXMLEditor";
   @Override
   public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
      /* Some implementation */ 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to use the `getAdapter` method:

```
IDocument doc = (IDocument)getAdapter(IDocument.class);
```

`XMLMultiPageEditorPart` is in an internal package and is consequently not part of the official API and is subject to change without notice.

Comment: So, by overriding classes from external packages, I can violate some license restrictions?

Comment: No I think the license is ok, it is just that the Eclipse designers did not intended for this class to be overridden. You may find that the class changes at a service release and things stop working. See this article: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html

Comment: Thank you, in that case I should look for alternative solutions of pre-save validation, without editor class modifying.